# Invoking sed on grep results - linux shell script / text processing

Tags: linux, bash, shell

What is the best way to invoke sed on grep results and save it to file?
I wanna to change some lines in text file e.g.

> Hi { Tom Mary Andy }
>
> What { Eric John Ted }
>
> Hi { Jerry Katy Mark }

So my problem is that i wanna add for example letter T. before all names that are included between brackets { } in lines that are "Hi" lines and overwrite file. Results should looks like that:

> Hi { T.Tom T.Mary T.Andy }
>
> What { Eric John Ted }
>
> Hi { T.Jerry T.Katy T.Mark }

What do you think is the best solution / commands? I'm going to write shell script to do that. I know that i can grep that lines, later change it to array and concat but i dont think that is a nice solution :) Thanks for your help.

Comment: In general, there's no need to do that: `sed` can do all the work that `grep` can itself (and `awk` is still more flexible than either). If you showed your `grep` line, we could show you how to fold it into `sed` (or implement the desired logic of both natively in `awk`).

Comment: ...if one doesn't mind some extra verbosity, the whole thing could be done natively in bash (with no external tools -- no `sed`, `grep` or `awk`) too.

Comment: Now I'm count the number of occurrences, create for loop in that range. Every iteration I save results of grep that returns current appearance, remove brackets and Hi command, change string variable to array and make for loop to add at the beggining of every word a T letter. At the end i sed the occurane of "Hi" line with my new changed Hi line.

Answer (score 6):

If you have:

```
Hi { Tom Mary Andy }
What { Eric John Ted }
Hi { Jerry Katy Mark }
```

and want to insert a `'T.'` before each capital letter in lines beginning with `'Hi`', to obtain:

```
Hi { T.Tom T.Mary T.Andy }
What { Eric John Ted }
Hi { T.Jerry T.Katy T.Mark }
```

Then you can do that with `sed` alone. To edit the file in place, use the `'-i'` option for `sed`:

```
sed -i '/^Hi/s/\s\([A-Z]\)/ T.\1/g' filename.txt
```

**note:** to create a backup of the original file, use `sed -i.bak`

If you are using a mac or other OS where `sed` is provided without the `'-i'` option, then you can use:

```
sed '/^Hi/s/\s\([A-Z]\)/ T.\1/g' < filename.txt > newfilename.txt
```

with the results in `newfilename.txt`

Comment: `-i` being non-POSIX-specified and incompatible in usage between GNU and Apple implementations, it's not ideal to suggest without explicit caveats.

Comment: Thanks for your fast help :) I have a one more question, how can i achieve the same but when te starting command will be e.g. 
> Hi Everyone { Tom Mark Katy }
Because using your formula the T is also inserted at the begginng of Everyone

Comment: Just make it `sed -i '/^Hi [{]/s/\s\([A-Z]\)/ T.\1/g' filename.txt` You are basically doing `sed /find/s/substitute/with/` so you can limit or expand each part as necessary. Note: `\1` is a backreference that repeats what what between `\(stuff\)` in the substitute part.